# dynamically creating linq with mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've just started using mongodb in c# and it's great however I'm struggling to understand how i could dynamically create a linq query to pass to mongodb.

Situation: I have a file that has some general properties filename, filesize ect, one of these properties is metadata, which is a list of fields with values.  the user will be able to specify the search criteria dynamically and so i cant hard code this query.

My Object for completeness:

```
public class asset
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public int filesize { get; set; }
    public List<shortmetadata> metadata { get; set; }
}

public class shortmetadata
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

My current code which is manually setting the search criteria and returns any asset that has "hello" or "world" in the metadata value field:

```
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("Test");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<asset>("assets");

        var assets = collection.AsQueryable().Where(i =>
        i.metadata.Any(m => m.value.Contains("hello")) ||
        i.metadata.Any(m => m.value.Contains("world")) 
        );
```

What i would like to be able to do is dynamically create the query based on the users selection (don't have this yet as want to get it working in code first!)

Any help would be great.

Comment: You can just chain the `Where(…)` calls on the `IQueryable` depending on the criteria and linq will resolve them into an expression  - or, [if you want to go deeper..](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/giving-clarity-to-linq-queries-by-extending-expressions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, for example, you had a Dictionary<string, string> containing the name value to search for keyed by the name of the meta item you could build your IQueryable<Asset> up in a loop like this

```
var query = collection.AsQueryable();
//Non-meta properties
query = query.Where(a => a.SomeNonMetaProperty == "Something");
//And now meta properties
foreach(var keyAndValue in someDictionary)
{
  query = query.Where(m => 
    m.Name == keyAndValue.Key
    && m.Value == keyAndValue.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Slazure](http://www.slazure.com/) lets you create dynamic Linq queries at runtime since its predicates are string literals.

> PM> Install-Package Slazure.MongoDB

```
// C# example: Build a document query that return employees that has a salary greater than $40k/year using a dynamic LINQ query filter.
dynamic storage = new QueryableStorage<DynDocument>("mongodb://user:pass@example.org/MongoDBExample");
QueryableCollection<DynDocument> employeesCollection = storage.Employees;
var employeeQuery = employeesCollection
    // Query for salary greater than $40k and born later than early '95.
    .Where("Salary > 40000 and Birthdate >= DateTime(1995,15,3)")
    // Projection and aliasing.
    .Select("new(_id as Email, Birthdate, Name, Timestamp as RegisteredDate)")
    // Order result set by birthdate descending.
    .OrderBy("Birthdate desc")
    // Paging: Skip the first 5 and retrieve only 5.
    .Skip(5).Take(5)
    // Group result set on Birthdate and then on Name.
    .GroupBy("Birthdate", "Name");

// Use a dynamic type so that we can get access to the document's dynamic properties
foreach (dynamic employee in employeeQuery)
{
    // Show some information about the employee
    Console.WriteLine("The employee '{0}' was employed {1} and was born in {2}.",
        employee.Email, employee.RegisteredDate, employee.Birthdate.Year);
}
```

It also supports substitution values which makes your predicate code look cleaner.

```
// C# example: Query the storage for employee that earn less than $60k/yr and that are born before the millennium.
var amount = 60000;
var employeeQuery = employeesTable.Where("Salary > @0 and Timestamp <= @1", amount, new DateTime(2000, 1, 1));
```